# How to poll the microcontroller?

Tags: c#, microcontroller, polling, modbus

I use the EasyModbus library to connect the computer with the microcontroller.

Problem: I need to read global registers / variables on the microcontroller via ModbusTCP <> it is not a single reading, it must check the state whether the given register has changed and assign its value to the variable / field (close to real time)

I know I need to poll the microcontroller, but I don't know how.

```
public static ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient();

void sth
{
 int[] registers = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(2500, 5);
}
```

Comment: You already posted code that reads from the controller. Do that in a loop or in a timer's callback

Comment: but i must do this in class, so I must have method who do in loop?